# Return objects with get_object and Retrieve UpdateAPIView

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views, backend

I am trying to use method put and return the changes of an instance of the user model with the token using get_object with RetrieveUpdateAPIView. But I only get the user data:

```
{
    "id": int,
    "username": "",
    "email": "",
    "is_staff": bool
}
```

Is there any way to get it like this?:

```
{
 "user": {
    "id": int,
    "username": "",
    "email": "",
    "is_staff": bool
  },
 "token": ""
}
```

This in order not to change the logic on frontend; get the token for authorization with: `user.token`

This is my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')
```

and this is my viewset:

```
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: please share the portion of the code you are asking for . However, you can use nested calls for this kind of situation

Comment: I added code, thanks.

Comment: where is this "token": "" coming from or whats its use ?

Comment: From LoginView: ```serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')

class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
serializer_class = UserSerializer

def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user

serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer      
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):         
   serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)         
   serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)         
   user = serializer.validated_data
   token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]         
   return Response({"user": UserSerializer(user, 
         context=self.get_serializer_context()).data, 
        "token":  token        })
```